# JSP - using a variable as the url in c:import

Tags: jsp, jstl

Is there any way that we can use a variable in a `<c:import>` statement in JSP such as:
`<c:import url="<%=_header%>"></c:import>`, where `_header` is a JSP String defined thus;

```
// host will typically equal: uk.domain.com or fr.domain.com
String host = request.getServerName();
// cc is attempting to become the country code for the domain
String cc = host.substring(0, host.indexOf("."));

String _header = "http://assets.domain.com/" + cc + "/includes/header_" + cc + ".jsp";
```

We host a number of sites across multiple markets. Being able to define one template this way would be ideal as it would mean fewer changes to templates. Unfortunately whenever including `<c:import url="<%=_header%>"></c:import>` the server fails to load the page.

But including, for instance: <strike>`<c:import url="http://assets.domain.com/uk/includes/header_uk.jsp?market=<%=cc%>"></c:import>`</strike> seems to work fine...

Any thoughts?!

---

**Edit:** Turns out the `<%=cc%>` var in the URL wasn't actually working. Had to do the following instead to get it to work;

```
String cc = host.substring(0, host.indexOf("."));
session.setAttribute("cc", cc);

...

<c:import url="http://assets.domain.com/uk/includes/header_uk.jsp"><c:param name="market">${cc}</c:param></c:import>
```

Still haven't solved the variable URL problem yet, however...

Comment: Unfortunately as we don't control the environment that we're working on, we can't narrow down the problem - any time the server detects a runtime error it redirects the browser to a 404 page. Not exactly helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably mix *scriptlets* with taglibs/EL. They runs in different moments and scopes. You should choose to use the one or the other. Since the use of *scriptlets* is officially [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) since JSP 2.0 (released Nov 2003), I'd recommend to drop it altogether and go ahead with taglibs/EL only.

The following *scriptlet*

```
<%
    // host will typically equal: uk.domain.com or fr.domain.com
    String host = request.getServerName();
    // cc is attempting to become the country code for the domain
    String cc = host.substring(0, host.indexOf("."));
%>
```

can be replaced by the following taglib/EL:

```xml
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<c:set var="cc" value="${fn:split(pageContext.request.serverName, '.')[0]}" />
```

so that it's available as `${cc}` in EL.

```xml
<c:import url="http://assets.domain.com/${cc}/includes/header_${cc}.jsp" />
```

Comment: That's really awesome to know, thank you very much! Time to start reading up on taglibs/EL I guess!

We've sort of been thrown in at the deepend with this CMS as none of us are really that confident in Java/JSP so it's been a great learning experience.

If I could vote up I would... damn me for being a newbie to Stack!

Comment: @Aito: press `Ask Question` button on right top and elaborate in detail.

Comment: @BalusC: Your solution didn't work for me. But then, after searching, I found the problem: I tried to use it inside a tag file, and it doesn't work if I don't put the 'isELIgnored="false"' flag. So, sorry, you were right. Thanks for posted it!

Comment: @Aito: You're welcome. In the future, please press `Ask Question` on right top instead of abusing comments to post questions.